# Firebase - Retrieving data from pushed items

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

I'm stuck on this issue of how to retrieve pushed data from firebase. I've got it set up with authentication and I had two users push a little bit of data:

```
{
  "deck" : {
    "-JkpwAnieKjQVsdtPD4m" : {
      "deckName" : "Deck 1",
      "color" : "Red",
      "user" : "simplelogin:1"
    },
    "-Jkq4unexm-qwhO_U2YO" : {
      "deckName" : "Deck 2",
      "color" : "Blue",
      "user" : "simplelogin:1"
    },
    "-Jkq5-II1q5yM6w3ytmG" : {
      "deckName" : "Deck 3",
      "color" : "Green",
      "user" : "simplelogin:6"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I run:

```
deckRef.once('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
  console.log(dataSnapshot.val());
});
```

Which returns the 3 pushed with their keys generated by push().

It seems there there a way with firebase to say retrieve all color entries that are made by "simplelogin:1" (so Red and Blue) but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for Firebase's queries, which allow you to:

```
deckRef.orderByChild('user').equalTo('simplelogin:1').on(...
```

Don't forget to add `user` to the `.indexOn` in your security rules.

See:

- [Firebase documentation on queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries)
- [Firebase documentation on indexing data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/indexing-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

query your data like this

```
deckRef.orderByKey().once('child_added', function(dataSnapshot) {
      console.log(dataSnapshot.val());
});
```

Note: `orderByKey()` works with `child_added` eventType

[Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#orderByKey)